# Problems w/ local repository in 16.04 with apt-mirror. How to update from client?

Tags: package-management, updates, repository, apt-mirror

Trying to setup a local repository for 16.04 using `apt-mirror` (both host and client are 16.04 LTS), but experiencing problems, amongst others, with authentication due a missing release file when running `sudo apt-get update` at the client.

I've followed [this guide](https://www.unixmen.com/setup-local-repository-in-ubuntu-15-04/) to setup the local repository.

**Host-side:**

`/etc/apt/mirror.list`:

```
############# config ##################
#
set base_path /repo
#
# set mirror_path  $base_path/mirror
# set skel_path    $base_path/skel
# set var_path     $base_path/var
# set cleanscript $var_path/clean.sh
# set defaultarch  <running host architecture>
# set postmirror_script $var_path/postmirror.sh
# set run_postmirror 0
set nthreads     20
set _tilde 0
#
############# end config ##############

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse


# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse

clean http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
```

For the apache-part, I have created the link `sudo ln -s /repo/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ ubuntu`, so no change compared to the guide.

**Client-side:**

On the client side I've only changed `http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/` to `http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu` in `/etc/apt/sources.list`, e.g.

```
deb http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
deb http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted

deb http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe

deb http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse
```

When running `sudo apt-get update` I get the following;

```
Ign:1 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Ign:2 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
Ign:3 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial Release
Ign:4 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates Release
Ign:5 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:6 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:7 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:8 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:9 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:10 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:11 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/restricted all Packages
Ign:12 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/restricted Translation-en
Ign:13 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:14 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/universe i386 Packages
Ign:15 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/universe all Packages
Ign:16 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/universe Translation-en
Ign:17 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:18 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:19 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/multiverse all Packages
Ign:20 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/multiverse Translation-en
Ign:21 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
Ign:22 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 Packages
Ign:23 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/main all Packages
Ign:24 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/main Translation-en
Ign:25 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:26 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:27 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted all Packages
Ign:28 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted Translation-en
Ign:29 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:30 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe i386 Packages
Ign:31 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe all Packages
Ign:32 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe Translation-en
Ign:33 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:34 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:35 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse all Packages
Ign:36 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Ign:5 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:6 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:7 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:8 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:9 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:10 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:11 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/restricted all Packages
Ign:12 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/restricted Translation-en
Ign:13 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:14 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/universe i386 Packages
Ign:15 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/universe all Packages
Ign:16 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/universe Translation-en
Ign:17 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:18 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:19 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/multiverse all Packages
Ign:20 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/multiverse Translation-en
Ign:21 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
Ign:22 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 Packages
Ign:23 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/main all Packages
Ign:24 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/main Translation-en
Ign:25 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:26 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:27 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted all Packages
Ign:28 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted Translation-en
Ign:29 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:30 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe i386 Packages
Ign:31 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe all Packages
Ign:32 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe Translation-en
Ign:33 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:34 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:35 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse all Packages
Ign:36 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Ign:5 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:6 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:7 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:8 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:9 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:10 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:11 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/restricted all Packages
Ign:12 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/restricted Translation-en
Ign:13 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:14 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/universe i386 Packages
Ign:15 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/universe all Packages
Ign:16 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/universe Translation-en
Ign:17 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:18 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:19 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/multiverse all Packages
Ign:20 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/multiverse Translation-en
Ign:21 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
Ign:22 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 Packages
Ign:23 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/main all Packages
Ign:24 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/main Translation-en
Ign:25 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:26 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:27 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted all Packages
Ign:28 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted Translation-en
Ign:29 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:30 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe i386 Packages
Ign:31 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe all Packages
Ign:32 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe Translation-en
Ign:33 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:34 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:35 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse all Packages
Ign:36 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Ign:5 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:6 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:7 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:8 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:9 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:10 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:11 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/restricted all Packages
Ign:12 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/restricted Translation-en
Ign:13 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:14 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/universe i386 Packages
Ign:15 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/universe all Packages
Ign:16 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/universe Translation-en
Ign:17 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:18 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:19 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/multiverse all Packages
Ign:20 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/multiverse Translation-en
Ign:21 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
Ign:22 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 Packages
Ign:23 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/main all Packages
Ign:24 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/main Translation-en
Ign:25 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:26 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:27 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted all Packages
Ign:28 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted Translation-en
Ign:29 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:30 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe i386 Packages
Ign:31 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe all Packages
Ign:32 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe Translation-en
Ign:33 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:34 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:35 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse all Packages
Ign:36 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Ign:5 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:6 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:7 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:8 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:9 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:10 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:11 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/restricted all Packages
Ign:12 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/restricted Translation-en
Ign:13 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:14 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/universe i386 Packages
Ign:15 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/universe all Packages
Ign:16 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/universe Translation-en
Ign:17 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:18 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:19 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/multiverse all Packages
Ign:20 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/multiverse Translation-en
Ign:21 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
Ign:22 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 Packages
Ign:23 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/main all Packages
Ign:24 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/main Translation-en
Ign:25 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:26 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:27 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted all Packages
Ign:28 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted Translation-en
Ign:29 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:30 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe i386 Packages
Ign:31 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe all Packages
Ign:32 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe Translation-en
Ign:33 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:34 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:35 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse all Packages
Ign:36 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Err:5 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign:6 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:7 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:8 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:9 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:10 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:11 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/restricted all Packages
Ign:12 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/restricted Translation-en
Ign:13 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:14 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/universe i386 Packages
Ign:15 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial/universe all Packages
Err:21 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign:22 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 Packages
Ign:23 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/main all Packages
Ign:24 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/main Translation-en
Ign:25 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:26 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:27 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted all Packages
Ign:28 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted Translation-en
Ign:29 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:30 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe i386 Packages
Ign:31 http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe all Packages
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu xenial-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://10.0.0.125/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Any suggestions to how to solve this? I've seen some other posts regarding `apt-mirror` and `16.04`, but it seems like everyone else who experience similar problems have solved theirs with solutions that doesn't work for me.

Comment: No one has any input at all?

Comment: This was solved by also downloading the i386-packages with apt-mirror to the server. I can't explain why that's the solution, but at least it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment of the question, this was solved by also adding the i386-packages to the local repository. Did the following, minor changes to `/etc/apt/mirror.list:` on the host-side (had to download approx 40GB extra in packages, if I remember correctly):

```
############# config ##################
#
set base_path /repo
#
# set mirror_path  $base_path/mirror
# set skel_path    $base_path/skel
# set var_path     $base_path/var
# set cleanscript $var_path/clean.sh
# set defaultarch  <running host architecture>
# set postmirror_script $var_path/postmirror.sh
# set run_postmirror 0
set nthreads     20
set _tilde 0
#
############# end config ##############

deb-amd64 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted universe multiverse
deb-amd64 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-amd64 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse

deb-i386 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted universe multiverse
deb-i386 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-i386 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse

clean http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
```

Can't explain why it works, but it does and it solved my problem. Stupid as it is.