# Error on local repository and download packages 32 and 64 not solving the problem

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, repository

i have the same problem with my local repository this guy had, [Problems w/ local repository in 16.04 with apt-mirror. How to update from client?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/817025/problems-w-local-repository-in-16-04-with-apt-mirror-how-to-update-from-client#new-answer?newreg=5d7dcd509808453e8b4040b1e6762d08)
but in my case set the download of deb-amd64 and deb-i386 did not fix the problem...

This is my mirror.list, i changed my company real name for mycompany

```
############# config ##################
#
set base_path    /media/isan/EXTRA/xenial-repo
#
# set mirror_path  $base_path/mirror
# set skel_path    $base_path/skel
# set var_path     $base_path/var
# set cleanscript $var_path/clean.sh
# set defaultarch  <running host architecture>
# set postmirror_script $var_path/postmirror.sh
# set run_postmirror 0
set nthreads     20
set _tilde 0
#
############# end config ##############

deb-amd64 http://espejo.mycompany.cu/~ubuntu xenial main restricted universe multiverse
deb-amd64 http://espejo.mycompany.cu/~ubuntu xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb-i386 http://espejo.mycompany.cu/~ubuntu xenial main restricted universe multiverse
#deb-i386 http://espejo.mycompany.cu/~ubuntu xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse


clean http://espejo.mycompany.cu/~ubuntu
```

The repository i'm pointing to works just fine when i call it directly, but when i use apt-mirror and point to the downloaded one i get this output(i wont copy paste the whole output, only the last beacause the top of the output its the same as always)

```
Des:20 file:/media/isan/EXTRA/xenial-repo xenial/universe Translation-en
Ign:20 file:/media/isan/EXTRA/xenial-repo xenial/universe Translation-en
Des:21 file:/media/isan/EXTRA/xenial-repo xenial/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:21 file:/media/isan/EXTRA/xenial-repo xenial/multiverse amd64 Packages
Des:22 file:/media/isan/EXTRA/xenial-repo xenial/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:22 file:/media/isan/EXTRA/xenial-repo xenial/multiverse i386 Packages
Des:23 file:/media/isan/EXTRA/xenial-repo xenial/multiverse all Packages
Ign:23 file:/media/isan/EXTRA/xenial-repo xenial/multiverse all Packages
Des:24 file:/media/isan/EXTRA/xenial-repo xenial/multiverse Translation-es_CU
Ign:24 file:/media/isan/EXTRA/xenial-repo xenial/multiverse Translation-es_CU
Des:25 file:/media/isan/EXTRA/xenial-repo xenial/multiverse Translation-es
Ign:25 file:/media/isan/EXTRA/xenial-repo xenial/multiverse Translation-es
Des:26 file:/media/isan/EXTRA/xenial-repo xenial/multiverse Translation-en
Ign:26 file:/media/isan/EXTRA/xenial-repo xenial/multiverse Translation-en
Des:3 file:/media/isan/EXTRA/xenial-repo xenial/main amd64 Packages
Err:3 file:/media/isan/EXTRA/xenial-repo xenial/main amd64 Packages
  Fichero no encontrado - /media/isan/EXTRA/xenial-repo/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages (2: No existe el archivo o el directorio)
Des:4 file:/media/isan/EXTRA/xenial-repo xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:4 file:/media/isan/EXTRA/xenial-repo xenial/main i386 Packages
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
N: No se podrán ignorar los privilegios para descargar mientras no se pueda acceder a «/media/isan/EXTRA/xenial-repo/dists/xenial/InRelease» con el usuario «_apt». - pkgAcquire::Run (13: Permiso denegado)
W: El repositorio «file:/media/isan/EXTRA/xenial-repo xenial Release» no tiene un fichero de Publicación.
N: Los datos de un repositorio como este no se pueden autenticar y por tanto su uso es potencialmente peligroso.
N: Vea la página de manual apt-secure(8) para los detalles sobre la creación de repositorios y la configuración de usuarios.
E: Fallo al obtener file:/media/isan/EXTRA/xenial-repo/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Fichero no encontrado - /media/isan/EXTRA/xenial-repo/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages (2: No existe el archivo o el directorio)
E: No se han podido descargar algunos archivos de índice, se han omitido, o se han utilizado unos antiguos en su lugar.
```

it throws security issues and not found errors...i have no idea why

This issue is driving me crazy, i been dealing with this about 3 weeks and every test takes me like 2 days because of the size of the repository.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved doint this things.

1. I pointed the sources.list to look inside deb file:///media/isan/EXTRA/xenial-repo/mirror/espejo.mycompany.cu/~ubuntu xenial main restricted universe multiverse
2. Erase all the content of the folder /var/lib/apt/lists using (sudo rm -R /var/lib/apt/lists)
3. i Used apt update instead of apt-get update, don't know if that's is a factor

i still have some warnings but it works, i think that getting the repo from an offline repository in an external HDD requires some permissions or more work to do..

i hope this helps somebody